# Read a flat text file and replace specific list of patterns using python

Tags: python

Need a help to read flat file and convert to following format.

**INPUT FLAT FILE  - commands.txt**

```
login to url as http://demo.url.net username as test@url.net and password as mytester create-the-folder with name fdemo 
share-the-folder to username user2@url.net 
logout

login to url as http://demo.url.net username as user2@url.net and password as mytester123 check-the-folder with name demo 
logout
```

Expected format after replace the patterns -  ['as','to','and','with]. "as" should replace as "="

```
login url=http://demo.url.net username=test@url.net password=mytester
create-the-folder name=fdemo
share-the-folder username=user2@url.net
logout

login url=http://demo.url.net username=user2@url.net password=mytester123
check-the-folder name=demo
logout
```

Please help me to get the result.

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use `str.replace` to replace parts of a string with something else.

Comment: Hi, I have created the following code to replace text but "as" keyword replacing password to p=sword. How can I correct it.       `code` import os,sys
def parseText(text):
text_pattern={"as":"=",'with':"","and":"","to":""}
for key,value in text_pattern.iteritems(): 
if key in text: 
text=text.replace(key,value)
text=text.replace("\r\n","")
return text
result = defaultdict(dict)
item = count()
list_out=[]
patterns=['as','with','to']
with open(os.path.abspath('catalog/commands1.txt'),'r') as f:
for line in f:
if not line:
continue
parts=parseText(line)
list_out.append(parts)
print list_out`code`

Comment: Please update your question with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the following code and able to achieve my expected result.

```
def formater():
    mydict=defaultdict(dict)
    mylist=[]
    with open('dict-values.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            mylist.append(line.strip())

        for item in mylist:
            key,value =item.split(':')
            mydict[key]=value
    return mydict

def parseText1(text):
    text_patterns=formater()
    for key,value in text_patterns.iteritems():
        pattern=re.compile(key)
        if pattern.findall(text):
            text=re.sub(key,value,text)
            text=re.sub('='+'\s','=',text)          
    return text

result = defaultdict(dict)
item = count()
list_out=[]
with open(os.path.abspath('catalog/commands1.txt'),'r') as fread:
    for line in fread:
        if not line:
            continue
        parts=parseText1(line)
        list_out.append(parts.rstrip())
        #list_out.append(parts.split())

print "AFTER - " + str(list_out)
```