# replace words in a text with loop

Tags: python, ruby, bash

I'm in the middle of a project and I need to replace a csv file contain username and passwords and ID numbers in a text and save them in a text file like below:

---

---csv:

```
username;password;id

User1;pass1;11

User2;pass2;12
```

---text:

```
your user name is USER and you password is PASS and your ID is ID
```

---result:

```
Hello your user name is USER1 and you password is PASS1 and your ID is 11

Hello your user name is USER2 and you password is PASS2 and your ID is 12
```

---

Is there any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Just curious...how is this question "unclear"? He/she has a csv file with `USER`, `PASS`, and `ID` in the form of `username;password;id`. He/she needs to open this file and save strings in a text file in the specified format. What's unclear about this?

Comment: @mevius There's no existing code to get a feel for what the "middle of the project" means - and thus it's difficult to get a feel for whether python, ruby or bash is better suited/desired. The question isn't unclear in the strictest sense, but the implementation is unclear - plus it does tend to read as "someone write this for me"...

Comment: oh I can explain more, I need to generate the Result text file from given csv file and put it in my config file for other usage in a web application, the Result text file can be generated with any scripting language but I don't know how!

Comment: @JonClements oh it was kinda like "someone write this for me" :| also I get some clue from this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790000/read-a-flat-text-file-and-replace-specific-list-of-patterns-using-python

Comment: That's going to be overkill for what you're after... if you're happy to use Python then you can use Alex's answer as a base.... just replace `USER1` and co. with `{}` so it does the replacements properly... and add `\n` to the end of the string so you get lines :)

Comment: @JonClements yeah thanks, it was helpful I'm trying to figure it out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(file1) as i, open(file2, 'w') as o:
    for line in i:
        o.write('Hello your user name is {0} and you 
                 password is {1} and your ID is {2}'.format(*line.split(';')))
```

Comment: Missing a couple of `{}s` in the format string me thinks :)